# Group by and change data

Tags: sql, sql-server

problem :
There are two columns. column1 and column2
column 1 might have some similar data(Tasks) and column 2 have true and false based on the user is assigned to that task or not.

I want to group by values and see if in the same tasks(column1) if there is even 1 false then make other similar tasks false too.

Can anyone help me with this?

```html
Value                               |PrimaryOwnerId
_______________________________________________________________________
EVP-RP&P                           |  true
Execution Coordinator                   |  true
Execution Coordinator                   |  flase
Inspection Lead                           |  true
Instrument, Electrical, and Analyzer      |  true
Logistics                           |  true
Logistics                           |  flase
Operations                           |  true
Planning                           |  true
```

I am using this query.

---

```
   select CraftName AS value,
case 
   when PrimaryOwnerID is Null 
       Then 'true'
       else 'flase'
       End as PrimaryOwnerID
        FROM EventTasks AS et
                          INNER JOIN EventMileStones AS em ON em.EventMileStoneID = et.EventMileStoneID
                          INNER JOIN LocationTasks AS lt ON lt.LocationTaskID = et.LocationTaskID
                          INNER JOIN Crafts AS c ON c.ID = lt.CraftID
                     WHERE ProjectID = 4
                     group by CraftName, PrimaryOwnerID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CTE for your query and then check with EXISTS if there is a not null PrimaryOwnerID for a value:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    CraftName AS value,
    PrimaryOwnerID,
  FROM EventTasks AS et
  INNER JOIN EventMileStones AS em ON em.EventMileStoneID = et.EventMileStoneID
  INNER JOIN LocationTasks AS lt ON lt.LocationTaskID = et.LocationTaskID
  INNER JOIN Crafts AS c ON c.ID = lt.CraftID
  WHERE ProjectID = 4
  GROUP BY CraftName, PrimaryOwnerID
)
select 
  c.value,
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from cte where value = c.value and PrimaryOwnerID is not null
    ) then 'false'
    else 'true'
  end PrimaryOwnerID
from cte c
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I am trying to run this query but it is giving me an error , Invalid column name c.CraftName.

Answer (score 0):

I think window functions are simpler.  Because you are using strings, `min()` works for your logic:

```
select CraftName AS value,
       min(PrimaryOwnerID) over (partition by CraftName) as new_PrimaryOwnerID
from EventTasks et join
     EventMileStones em 
     on em.EventMileStoneID = et.EventMileStoneID join
     LocationTasks lt 
     on lt.LocationTaskID = et.LocationTaskID join
     Crafts c 
     on c.ID = lt.CraftID
where ProjectID = 4
group by CraftName, PrimaryOwnerID;
```

No subqueries or CTEs are needed.